# Incorrect layout rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page which displays my testimonials in the `my_testimonials` action of the testimonials controller.

The correct layout for this action is `layouts/frame` but I must have changed something because now it is rendering `layouts/application`

Here is the layout being specified in the controller:

```
layout "layouts/frame", only: [:my_testimonials]
layout "layouts/shares", only: [:new]
```

Here is the output in the console:

```
Started GET "/my_testimonials/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b" for 105.228.65.202 at 2013-09-27 07:40:49 +0000
2013-09-27T07:40:49.470211+00:00 app[web.2]: Processing by TestimonialsController#my_testimonials as HTML
2013-09-27T07:40:49.686047+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered testimonials/_testimonial.html.erb (2.6ms)
2013-09-27T07:40:49.686200+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered testimonials/my_testimonials.html.erb within layouts/application (79.2ms)
```

The testimonials are being displayed but with the incorrect layout. As I said it was working yesterday so I must have changed some small detail or the order of something.

Comment: It probably will not make a difference, but i usually write `layout "frame"`, so i think the `layouts` folder is not needed (the less you need to write the better).

Comment: @nathandva, apologies, I didn't see your comment before posting my answer.

Comment: It didn't make a difference. I made the changes but no change in layout rendering. I'm now assuming it's a typo somewhere but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm inclined to think that a `layout()` call overrides previous calls. In this case, that the last `layout()` call you did for `:new` overrode the one for `:my_testimonials`.

You can also [choose the layout at runtime](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#choosing-layouts-at-runtime):

```
layout :set_layout

protected

def set_layout
  case action_name.to_sym
  when :my_testimonials
    'frame'
  when :new
    'shares'
  else
    'application'
  end
end
```

Or specify your layout per action:

```
def my_testimonials
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => 'frame' }
  end
end
```

---

**Update:**

[The code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/14c196e5a3f78ea4672b691a09ba60524b31fb73/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/layouts.rb#L261) suggests they do override previous calls. So calling `layout "layouts/shares", only: [:new]` is essentially saying to use "shares" for `:new` and "application" otherwise.

Comment: @spuggy: Don't forget to accept the answer if there are no other related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Rails looks for the layout in the 'app/layouts/' folder. See [Section 2.2.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

So, when you specify 'layouts/frame', rails looks for 'app/layouts/layouts/frame', which it obviously cannot find.

Change your layout directives to the following:

```
layout "frame", only: [:my_testimonials]
layout "shares", only: [:new]
```

Comment: I made the changes but it's still using the application layout. I am stumped. Anything else I can check?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
layout "layouts/frame"
```

to

```
layout 'frame'
```

I think this should work.

Comment: I made the changes but it's still using the application layout. I am stumped. Anything else I can check?

Comment: maybe check if you are not rendering application layout in the view, or just restart the application.